# ERROR => Received: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated in sendmail

Tags: shell, email, authentication, client, sendmail

I got this:

> ERROR => Received:    530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

I get this error when try to send a email through sendmail. The connectivity to mail server is fine, even I can telnet to the mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link might be helpful for you.
[Click](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/60e9fe06-2c16-429b-ba7b-dac4e5e2bf52/530-571-client-was-not-authenticated?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy) here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set UseDefaultCredentials to true: see sample powershell code

```
#SMTP server name
$smtpServer = "abcd.com.au"
$OFS = "`r`n`r`n"

#Creating a Mail object
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

#Creating SMTP server object
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

#Creating SMTP server object
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

#Email structure 
$msg.From = "abcd@abc.com.au"
$msg.ReplyTo = "abcd@abc.com.au"
$msg.To.Add("xyz@axyz.com.au")
$msg.subject = "Sample Sub (" + $a + " )"
$msg.body = "This is sample mail" + $OFS

# Attach a file 
$file = "C:\sample.txt"
$attachment = new-object System.Net.Mail.Attachment $file
$msg.Attachments.Add($file)

#Sending email 
$smtp.Send($msg)
```